# Writing a rational function representing Average cost over time. (Pre-Calc)

Tags: functions, rational-functions

I have a linear function that is C(t) = 4999.99 + 36(t)

where C(t) = Cost @ year after purchase

And t = years since purchase

-

AC(t) = (4,999.99 +36(t)) / (t)

(This is my funciton)

-

But, acording to my projects description. AC(t) (average cost over time is AC(t) = C(t) / t

but every time i graph it i get something that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQUSY.png)

But i know it needs to look something like a curve.

Im confused since the projects description says to do this:

```
⦁   The average cost, in dollars per year, AC(t)  , will turn out to be the total cost divided by  . AC(t)   is a rational function.  Write the rational function representing the average cost function per year for your device.
```

Comment: I mean ... it is a rational function, though? A rational function is a ratio of two polynomials. You have

$$AC(t) = \frac{4999.99 + 36t}{t}$$

Both the numerator and denominator are polynomials, so it is a rational function. The behavior of the graph even makes sense (if you take $t>0$ since "negative time" doesn't make sense) - the coefficient of $t$ in the numerator is small, so of course for very small $t$ (particularly $t<1$) you'll have a high value. I guess it might help to limit yourself to $t\geq 1$ since it wouldn't make sense to use intervals of years when it's not even 1 year.

Comment: Maybe I'm just not seeing what exactly the issue is. What kind of curve are you talking about?

Comment: @EeveeTrainer im confused as why the graph is decreasing, shouldn't the average cost of the product each year be greater than the starting price?

Comment: The thing is that, sure, you make a greater starting cost (which I assume to be the 4999.99 which I round to 5000 going forward), but you only pay 36 extra every successive year. So 1 year down the road, your total investment is only 5036. 2 years down the road, your total investment is 5072 - but over two years, that averages only 2536. After 3 years, the investment is 5108 - but over three years, that's an average of only about 1702. Notice the key point - that over time, your **total** investment increases, but your average investment gets smaller.

Comment: No, because you pay the initial 5000 only once.

Comment: A minor anecdote. If you ever go on to study calculus, this can be explained in terms of "limits." If you imagine $t$ growing infinitely large, then $AC(t)$ will become closer and closer to 36. This is because, if we take the limit of a rational function

$$f(x) = \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$$

where $P,Q$ are polynomials, then, as $x$ grows larger and larger, and if the highest exponent in $P, Q$ are the same, then $f(x)$ becomes closer and closer to whatever the coefficient of the highest power in $P$ is. You can imagine this in a more simple manner by graphing

$$f(x) = \frac{x^2 + 3}{x^2}$$

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Okay, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing fine.  The total cost is $5000$ at the start and $36$ per year thereafter.  The average cost starts very high and decreases as the $5000$ gets averaged over more years.  It would be better to plot your curve over a range like $0-10$ or $0-30$, not up into the hundreds.  You can write the average cost as $\frac {5000}t+36$ and you can see that at $t=1$ it will be $5036$, at $t=2$ it will be $2518$ and so on.